# Javascript - Add class to child of li class on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple list items with link elements inside.

In the example below, what Javascript function could I use to add class="selected" to the link inside the "coffee" list on page load.

```
<li class="coffee">
<a href="#"> ..... </a>
</li>

<li class="tea">
<a href="#"> ..... </a>
</li>

<li class="coke">
<a href="#"> ..... </a>
</li>

<li class="beer">
<a href="#"> ..... </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Really! `$('.coffee a').addClass('selected')`

Comment: But I need to add the class to the <a> item, not the <li>

Answer (score 1):

You can chain selector items to target child elements:

```
$('li.coffee a').addClass('selected');
```

This targets any `a` which is a descendant of any `li` with the class `coffee`.  You can also restrict it to *immediate* child elements:

```
$('li.coffee > a').addClass('selected');
```